# Remove Digits after decimal point from localized Number in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery Globalisation. I have formatted a number in "en-US" locale. 
For Eg.
       Number is: 95565680
  Localized number is: 95,565,680.00

I want  only 95,565,680. So How can I remove digits or zeros after decimal point?

Comment: Take care in spelling JavaScript. http://javascriptisnotjava.com

Answer (score 0):

use `split`

```
var i= "95,565,680.00"
alert(i.split(".")[0])//95,565,680
```